# AudioKit AKPlayer will be silent when the wired earphone connet

Tags: audiokit

i use AudioKit to make a vocalize app for student in china. And AudioKit is very powerful.

But i found a problem when i use AKPlayer to play some song.

```
    var aPlayer : AKPlayer!

    do {
        let audioFile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "mysong.mp3", baseDir: .resources)
        aPlayer = AKPlayer(audioFile: audioFile)
        aPlayer.isLooping = true
    }catch{

    }

    AudioKit.output = aPlayer
    do{
        try AudioKit.start()
    }catch{
        print("AudioKit.start() !!!")
    }

    aPlayer.play()
```

when the earphone connect my iPhone6s, no sound out form the earphone.
it's same situation when the earphone been pull out.

only pause and resume the Player can run again